# Multiple ssh login/logout

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I am dealing with ssh and my task is to log in to another console multiple times in non-interactive (?) mode so I specifically log on the machine in such mode that I have to type CTRL-D to log out, and this operation repeats.

```
 #!/bin/bash  
for i in `seq 100`  
do  
ssh test@macintel  
sleep 1  
done
```

Is there any way so I dont have to type CTRL-D manually to logout?

Running any command like `ssh test@macintel './command.sh'` does not work for me.

I was thinking of killing it by its PID, or invoking it with some file descriptor but I still have my local session blocked by invoked ssh connection.

Comment: Please clarify "Running any command like ssh test@macintel './command.sh' does not work for me" -- what goes wrong?  What commands have you tried?

Comment: I meant that usage runs non-login shell whereas I need it to be login shell instead. This is because we have software that couts it and whole case is about couting loggins. But when I run ssh test@macintel my current widnow/session is 'blocked' because of connection to another client and I have no idea how to automatically break the connection in this for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -l root 192.168.22.250 -C "./command.sh"
```

Use the `-C` option to pass through the command you wish to execute on the remote machine,

Comment: This is still slightly diffrent than login via simple ssh root@machine. We use some software that couts only physical login or logging in as I mentioned before. So task is to log in and then somehow break the connection (or exit 0 ). Running some command as You suggested does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but change the default shell on `macintel` to logout, so that you are logged out as soon as you log in:

```
sudo chmod -s logout test
```

The command must be run as root on `macintel` since logout is not a standard shell.

Answer (score 0):

This works on redhat boxes:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in seq 100
do
ssh user@server "/path/command.sh;exit"
done
```

Comment: same thing.. requests "exec" instead of "shell"

Answer (score 0):

Accorrding to ssh -vv log here what is invoked
if    `ssh -vv root@host "command;exit"` output of ssh shows:

`debug1: Sending command: command;exit

 debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1

...

debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0`

Whereas invoking `ssh -v root@host`  outputs:

`debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0

debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0

...

debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0

Last login: Wed Jul 11 09:11:22 2012 from 192.168.11.2`

So it looks like I need "shell" called while ssh logging.

@chepner: Your solution seems to by ok, but I cant change account settings in such way. Anyway thanks for idea.